# Cannot delete free partition

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, diskpart

I had an Ubuntu install, but it's taking up too much space and I'm getting a laptop on which I will install ubuntu, so I decided to remove the Ubuntu partition. I went into diskmgmt.msc and freed the Ubuntu partition. Now I need to delete it. I right click it, selected delete, but then get this error:

[image: error deleting partition]

When I try in DISKPART, I get the error "Virtual Disk Service error: the extended partition is not empty."

[image: DISKPART error]

How can I delete this free partition, thus making room for me to extend my C:\ partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out a solution. I deleted the 8gB partition, which was created by Ubuntu as a swap partition, and was then able to delete the original Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Good. You have figured out another option was boot from **Ubuntu live CD** and use **gparted**